# Paging in Common Table Value Expression(CTE), OFFSET/FETCH and Inner SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 queries. First is,

```
SELECT TOP (10)
    Products.*,
    Images.[ID] AS [ImageID],
    Images.[Path] AS [ImagePath]
FROM (SELECT
    Products.[ID] AS [Id1],
    Products.[Name] AS [Name],
    Products.[Price] AS [Price],
    Products.[NewPrice] AS [NewPrice],
    Products.[ShortDescription] AS [ShortDescription],
    Products.[SKU] AS [SKU],
    Products.[ProductTypeID] AS [ProductTypeID],
    Products.[ImageID] AS [ImageID],
    Products.[Promotion] AS [Promotion],
    Products.[ParentID] AS [ParentID],
    Products.[Attributes] AS [Attributes],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Products.[ID] ASC) AS [row_number]
FROM [dbo].[Products] AS Products) AS Products
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Images] AS Images
    ON Products.[ImageID] = Images.[ID]
WHERE Products.[row_number] > (1 - 1) * 10
ORDER BY Products.[ID1] ASC
```

which gives me,

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(10 row(s) affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Products'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1518, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Images'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 156 ms,  elapsed time = 145 ms.
```

and a second query,

```
WITH CTEPage
AS (SELECT
    Products.[ID] AS [Id1],
    Products.[Name] AS [Name],
    Products.[Price] AS [Price],
    Products.[NewPrice] AS [NewPrice],
    Products.[ShortDescription] AS [ShortDescription],
    Products.[SKU] AS [SKU],
    Products.[ProductTypeID] AS [ProductTypeID],
    Products.[ImageID] AS [ImageID],
    Products.[Promotion] AS [Promotion],
    Products.[ParentID] AS [ParentID],
    Products.[Attributes] AS [Attributes],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Products.[ID] ASC) AS [row_number]
FROM [dbo].[Products] AS Products)
SELECT TOP(10)
    Products.*
FROM CTEPage AS Products
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Images] AS Images
    ON Products.[ImageID] = Images.[ID]
WHERE Products.[row_number] > (1 - 1) * 10
ORDER BY Products.[ID1] ASC
```

which gives me,

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.

(10 row(s) affected)
Table 'Products'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

and using Fetch and OFFSET,

```
SELECT
        Products.[ID] AS [Id1],
        Products.[Name] AS [Name],
        Products.[Price] AS [Price],
        Products.[NewPrice] AS [NewPrice],
        Products.[ShortDescription] AS [ShortDescription],
        Products.[SKU] AS [SKU],
        Products.[ProductTypeID] AS [ProductTypeID],
        Products.[ImageID] AS [ImageID],
        Products.[Promotion] AS [Promotion],
        Products.[ParentID] AS [ParentID],
        Products.[Attributes] AS [Attributes],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Products.[ID] ASC) AS [row_number]
    FROM [dbo].[Products] AS Products
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Images] AS Images
        ON Products.[ImageID] = Images.[ID]
ORDER BY Products.[ID] ASC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

gives me,

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.

(10 row(s) affected)
Table 'Products'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

Which one should I use and better for me?

Comment: What's even the difference? You only inlined the CTE? CTE's are inlined by the query processor anyway. They never have a performance impact at all.

Comment: @usr Thanks. Using OFFSET and FETCH will be best in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTE's are inlined by the query processor anyway. They never have a performance impact at all.

Whether using OFFSET and FETCH is faster or not depends on the concrete query plan. There is no logical reason why it should be slower or faster but it tends to produce different plans. I think that is actually a flaw in the query optimizer.

I don't think this question will turn out to be useful to you. [You should probably research how to optimize paging in general.](https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=sql%20server%20optimize%20paging) You are too focused on the particular issues of CTE and OFFSET/FETCH which are not that meaningful.

Answer (score -1):

Use OFFSET and FETCH command in SQL Server 2012 for better performance.

http://dbadiaries.com/new-t-sql-features-in-sql-server-2012-offset-and-fetch

Comment: It's giving me the same result as CTEPage. There is no advantage of using it.